# simulate hover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list filled with images and descriptions like this:

```
<li>
<img class="photography"  src="PHOTO/boat.jpg" alt="Boat on sea." />
</li>
<li><div id="description" class="description">
<p>BOAT</p>
<p>ITALY</p>
</div></li>
<li>
```

I would like to simulate a hover event on the picture when i hover over the description div.
Can someone please hellp me on this?

Comment: Why don't you call the blur plugin on mouseEnter event?

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#description").mouseout(function(){
    $(".photography").css('border','');
});

$("#description").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".photography").css('border','4px solid #333');
});
```

[demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/79cf6/5)

Comment: Thx but i need something like this : onClick="$('.jp-pause').click();
The list is long and i need it to simulate hover on the previous element...

Comment: @a13k I have no idea what you're looking about

Comment: I'm using a plugin (pixastic) that converts images into canvas and blurs them when i hover over they become sharp now i added descriptions on the right of every image and i need the pictures to become sharp when i go over there descriptions ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a big div around your complete list and use this hover event.

Comment: hmm jeah i could but it's not that simple i need exactly this because i used some effects in my gallery that requier a hover on the image and nothing else ...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which functions and parameters you are using but here is an example that you can modify.

```
$("#description").mouseout(function(){
    $(".photography").pixastic("blurfast", {amount:0.2})
});

$("#description").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".photography").pixastic("revert")
});
```

Comment: ok this is ok but i have to access the previous element with the class photography ... so when i hover over description it then does something like this.prev(".photography")...